# Draw horizontal line in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

The question might seem to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787121/jtextpane-and-horizontal-lines) but it actually is not. So before downvoting this question, please clarify if any confusion.

I want to draw a horizontal line after every 6-7 lines in my `JTextPane` I am using `StyledDocument` and inserting strings to my `JTextPane` at runtime. Something like:

```
String myStr = "Some program-generated text";
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), myStr, attributeSet);
```

Now how do I draw a horizontal line after every few lines? I tried

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setContentType("text/html");
textPane.setText("<html>Some Text Above The Line<hr size=5>Some Text Below</html>");
```

But currently my app uses `setContentType("text/plain");` changing it to `Text.html` disturbs the whole UI. Furthermore, if I use `SetText()` then it would be inserted as fresh text, all the previous text will be gone which I appended with `doc.insertString();`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this!?

[image: Screenshot of Sample Application]

Start by creating your own subclass of JTextPane.  Implement the draw method and use the FontMetrics from the Graphics Context to get the height of your text.

```
public class MyTextPane extends JTextPane {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 128));

        FontMetrics fm = g2.getFontMetrics();
        int textHeight = fm.getHeight();

        for (int i = textHeight; i < getHeight(); i += (6 * textHeight)) {
            g2.drawLine(0, i + 1, getWidth(), i + 1);
        }

        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how do I call it?

Answer (score 1):

you can call it by editing your main method to call the `MyTextPane()` subclass instead of `JTextPane()` I.e.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //add your jframe here
    JFrame frame=new  JFrame();
    //add component
    MyTextPane pane1=new MyTextPane();
    pane1.setText("text here");
    frame.add(pane1);
    frame.pack();
    frame1.setVisible(true);
}
```